# shredpreference session android not direct to login page after logout

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

Hi i have a problem with my android login session function, which is my application do not direct to login page after hiting logout, when the application is not clear from recent apps menu. if the apps is still on recent apps then when we open it, it is going to main activity directly even in logout status. but after we clear the apps and then open it again, it works well. how to fix it ?

This is my sessionManager class

```
public class LoginSession {

// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpreference file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "akun";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";


// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_ID = "technician_id";

// Constructor
public LoginSession(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}


/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String name, String technician_id){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_ID, technician_id);

    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(this.isLoggedOff()){
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);

    }

}



/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUser(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user name
    user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
    user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));
    // return user
    return user;
}
/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
    OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
}

/**
 * Quick check for login
 * **/
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedOff(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

Note: i just call logout user for logout and in loginActivity i call checkLogin() function

Comment: LoginSession class not getting context of your calling activity or fragment

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `finish()` after logout.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

with,

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: but i use both of them

Comment: same. problem still exist